# Is it possible to install on a CRT based iMac (the large, fat, old ones)

Tags: installation, mac

I have a very old mac from a very long time ago, it looks like this: [image]

I don't know if this is the exact model but it is the exact color

My question is: is it of any possibility that I install a modern version of ubuntu onto it

PS... It is running os 9.2 if that will help distinguish the model

Answer (score 4):

The Mac you have (which looks like it's probably an [iMac G3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMac_G3)) has a PowerPC processor.  While Ubuntu stopped officially supporting this architecture in 2007, there are [community-maintained releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCDownloads) for PowerPC.  [Download the Ubuntu 10.10 ISO for PPC](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ports/releases/maverick/release/ubuntu-10.10-desktop-powerpc.iso), and you should be able to get it up and running on your iMac.  If you run into problems along the way, there are some iMac G3-specific discussions in the Ubuntu Forums or you can always ask about things here. :)  Good luck!

Comment: I tried installing the powerpc version on my mac, but it kept finding corrupt files when installing the base system, finally I got debian, which was as closest linux distro to ubuntu that officially supported PowerPC, but thanks for the help

Comment: Sorry Ubuntu didn't work out for you, but glad you found something that worked.

Comment: yeah, it's great, the computer is usable again :D

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should be possible

Here is a [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Intel_iMac) to some community information describing the information you will need to understand and implement.

Comment: That is not an Intel Mac.